# HTML CSS - Layout breaks on zooming

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have some problem with my layout. It looks good on my computer when I zoom to 100%. But when I zoom in or out the layout breaks. I tried several ways to wrap the layout but it didn't work so far. Since I need the layout to be responsive, any help is appreciated.

html:

```
<body>
<div class="low_wrapper">
<div id="intro" class="category">
<p><span class="category_description"><h1>Intro</h1></span></p>
<div class="low_info_header" >head</div>
<div class="low_info_element_big"></div>
<div class="low_info_element_big"></div>
<div class="low_info_header" >head</div>
</div>

<div id="women" class="category">
<h1>Women</h1>
<div class="low_info_header" >head</div>
<div class="low_info_element_big"></div>
<div class="low_info_element_big"></div>
<div class="low_info_header" >head</div>
</div>


</div>
</body>
```

css:

```
body{
margin: 0 0 0 0 ;
}

.category h1{
float:left;
width:940px;
font-family:'Open Sans';
}
.low_wrapper{
position:absolute;
margin-left:30px;
margin-top:30px;
position:absolute;
}

#low_info{
margin: 0 0 0px 33px;
width:940px;
background-color: #ccc;
float:left;
}

.low_info_header{
width:940px;
height:120px;
background-color:#FF0A83;
float:left;
position:relative;
}


.low_info_element_big{
height:400px;
width:460px;
background-color:#FF0A83;
margin-top:10px;
margin-right:20px;
margin-bottom:10px;
float:left;
position:relative;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MsUTp/1/

Comment: First of all when you are going responsive, most of them use `%`, I don't know what kind of responsive are you making, I hope you are not expecting any fluidity out of this

Comment: You're better off looking at media queries if you want responsive.

Comment: no, I dont expect fluidity. I just don't want the elements to float around while zooming.

Comment: I'm using bootstrap now, works great

Answer (score 1):

In your .css you are giving your elements specfic sizes with `px`. If you want your layout to resize with your screen you should apply size to your elements using `%` (i.e a percent of the screen size). This way when your screen size changes, your elements will resize relative to it keeping your layout the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    body {
    margin: 0 0 0 0 ;
    }

.category h1 {
    width:940px;
    font-family:'Open Sans';
    }

.low_wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-top:30px;
    position:absolute;
    }

#low_info {
   margin: 0 0 0px 33px;
   width:940px;
   background-color: #ccc;
   float:left;
   }

.low_info_header {
   width:100%;
   height:120px;
   background-color:#FF0A83;
   position:relative;
   }


.low_info_element_big {
   height:400px;
   width:460px;
   background-color:#FF0A83;
   margin-top:10px;
   margin-right:20px;
   margin-bottom:10px;
   position:relative;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd add in  a .wrapper class and change .low_wrapper { position:relative} instead of absolute

```
.wrapper {
width:960px;
}

.low_wrapper {
position:relative;
margin-left:30px;
margin-top:30px;

}
```

see example: http://jsfiddle.net/MsUTp/2/